# How to execute two if statements

Tags: php

I have two user types. Some who signup on the site and some who sigh up with facebook.

If the user signup with facebook i'm loading the profile picture.
The problem is that i only want to load a picture if they come from facebook, and my code so far doesn't load the content after my elseif statement

```
<body>
<!--  After user login  -->
  <?php if ($_SESSION['Femail']): ?> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['FIRST_NAME']; ?></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
      <?php elseif ($_SESSION['FBID']): ?> 
        <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['FBID']; ?>/picture">
        <div>
          <div id="userProfile">

        </div>
        <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
      </div>
    </div>

   <?php else: ?> 
    <h3>Not logged in</h3>
  <?php endif ?>
</body>
```

How do i load the profile picuture in my elseif statement without ending my first if statement?

Comment: What you mean by "without ending my first if statement"?

Comment: Why don't you just make 2 seperate if statements?

Comment: what does `var_dump($_SESSION['Femail'])` returns if a user sigh up with facebook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `if`-`endif` pair, like this:

```
<body>
<!--  After user login  -->
  <?php if ($_SESSION['Femail']): ?> 

    <div class="container">
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['FIRST_NAME']; ?></h1>
      </div>

      <div class="span4">
        <?php if ($_SESSION['FBID']): ?> 
          <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $_SESSION['FBID']; ?>/picture">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div>
          <div id="userProfile">
        </div>
        <a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  <?php else: ?> 
    <h3>Not logged in</h3>
  <?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

You can nest control statements as deeply as you like.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Works like a charm. I tried that earlier, but somehow i didn't manage to get it correct since it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

> *"All users <strike>has</strike> have the session 'Femail'"*

Remove the `elseif` and replace it with a regular `if`, otherwise the `elseif` block will never execute because *"All users <strike>has</strike> have the session `'Femail'`"*